# How inaccurate are empirical copulas when fit on real data?

Tags: copula, binning

Copula models are used widely to present the dependency structure among variables. However, they are often implemented by fitting well-known bivariate copulas like Gumbel and Clayton over the data. Obviously I don't see why anyone should expect a perfect fit from a pre-made cast object, so I'm not asking about this case.

Instead of fitting these pre-made molds over the data, but instead an *empirical copula* is constructed  based entirely on the actual real data through discretized binning of the uniform-transformed marginals, how accurate are these empirical copulas compared to the pre-made Archimedeans/Gumbels/Claytons? Are empirical copulas able to present >90% of the true dependency structure between variables? 80%? 50%? How to measure misestimation in copulas?

Comment: As with all empirical procedures, it depends on the strength of any signal in your data vs all the noise. It would be similar to the issue of how well a PCA describes your data which is widely discussed on this site. Copulas and PCA are related as both are representations of the covariance matrix that allow mixing of variables to reproduce a specified correlation structure.

Comment: @ReneBt You do a bit of disservice to the copula concept by characterizing it as a mere "representation of the covariance matrix," because the copula (together with the marginal distributions, of course) represents the full joint distribution.

Comment: do (empirical) copula pick up non-linear codependence between variables, both in the bivariate and multivariate case? if so is there a source that states/explores this

Comment: @whuber, that is true but comments aren't suitable for getting into details. I hadn't intended it to be read as merely that, but that one aspect of it that could be explored further since there is a lot of discussion around this in the context of PCA, which would be informative, while not directly answering the question.

Comment: Nonlinear in used two distinct ways that pop up in similar circumstances. If the shape of the relationship between the values of the variables is not a straight line ( but the coefficients remain constant) this is dealt with by marginal distributions applied after the copula. If the variable values influence the coefficients of the relationship that goes beyond where I've went with copulas. Some links about nonlinear multivariate data and copulas: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07269 http://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09659v1